# ec2.Instance' object is not iterable

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Im trying to copy the specified ec2 tags to their respective volumes. the function is invoked when the instance state changed to 'running'. However I don't want the code to run on every instance--for the first version of the code, when it as invoked my a single instance, it ran on all instances. even those that were already tagged. I want to have it run only for the specific instances that are booting up.

with some changes, Im getting **error: ec2.Instance' object is not iterable**
im really new to python and not sure how to proceed. Any inputs from you bright minds?

----HERE IS MY LAMBDA CODE----

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # is_test = context.function_name == 'test'  # this value is injected by SAM local
    
    instance = boto3.resource('ec2').Instance(id=event["detail"]["instance-id"])
   
    
    tags_to_use = ['Stack-Name', 'StackID']

    for instance in instance:
        tags = instance.tags
        to_tag = [t for t in tags if t['Key'] in tags_to_use]
        for vol in instance.volumes.all():
            print(f"Tagging volume {vol.id} from instance {instance.id}")
            vol.create_tags(Tags=to_tag)
```

Comment: You're getting a single instance in the first line of the handler then trying to do `for instance in instance` - why? Nevermind that `Instance` object is not iterable, that line does not make sense even if it were.

Comment: **Translation:** Just remove that line!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. as I said i'm learning and really appreciate your input. I removed that line and got this :                                                               {
  "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 8, in lambda_handler\n    print(instance.tags)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py\", line 345, in property_loader\n    return self.meta.data.get(name)\n"
  ]
}